# Setting push notification in Parse server hosted in heroku

Tags: ios, heroku, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I am beginner to parse server and heroku. I have migrated successfully to heroku by this tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOG50F_mXcQ

Then, I need to set up push notification. I am reading about this.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push

They say I need to write this. Where and what shall I write? ("....")
I can create pem file for my app. But I also don't know how to put in parse server. How shall I do?

```
  var server = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: '...',
    cloud: '...',
    appId: '...',
    masterKey: '...',
    push: {
      android: {
        senderId: '...',
        apiKey: '...'
      },
      ios: {
        pfx: '/file/path/to/XXX.p12',
        bundleId: '',
        production: false
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is set up in the index.js file. The vide you watched had you edit it at about 8 minutes in. The '...' need to be your apps personal senderID and apiKey. If you already had push notifications working on Parse.com, than these should be in the App Settings under push. The other items are already filled out.

Answer (score 0):

Note - This is just answer for part of the question, I was having similar question so thought to append the details here so other can use it.
adding where to store the .P12 file for iOS push notification.

Create a folder in your parse server app called certificates and copy the .p12 file there. If you added the folder locally, make sure you are pushing the revised directory to server.

iOS part would look something like this.

```
ios: {
        pfx: '/certificates/XXX.p12',
        bundleId: '',
        production: false
      }
```